# Change name of @CollectionTable in each derived classes

Tags: hibernate

I have `Base class` and two `Derived classes`. I want to change the new generated name each basic type property table names.
It is throwing an Exception,

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map for .... for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(properties)]